# If my Schengen VISA request gets refused will my data be stored in the Schengen Information System (SIS)?

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals

If my Schengen VISA request gets refused will my data be stored in the Schengen Information System (SIS) ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to ask about the [SIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Information_System) and not the [VIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_Information_System)?